# Angular HttpClient Request recursive body data

Tags: angular-httpclient

I would like to ask if anyone knows how does Angular HttpClient deal with request's recursive body data, e.g. if I pass in a Spaceship object that contains a Core object and a Engine object, and both of these contain a Spaceship object as a spaceship they belong to, the request goes through even though there is an obvious recursive dependency going on.

I wasn't able to find anything on this topic, RxJS AJAX doesn't support this and thorws a 'circular structure' error.

I would like to replicate Angular HttpClient's behaviour in other frameworks as well.

Would anyone know what does the charm?